# Google API scope drive.file includes drive.metadata

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm requesting authorization codes using the Google API and specify `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` as the required scope since I'm going to store files on the users drives.

However, when I'm authenticating it says my application requests permission for two scopes, both

> View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app

and

> View metadata for files in your Google Drive

I can verify that I indeed have access to list all files on the drive.

Is the `drive.metadata` automatically included/required for the scope i'm requesting?

I wish to ask for as few permissions as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drive v3 scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3)

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  View and manage the files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata  View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly    View metadata for files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly  View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly View the files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts  Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior

You cant view metadata on a file you dont have access to see.  Yes you need to be able to see them.  Google is smart they know if you want to want to see the metadata your going to have to also need the ability to see the file in question.  So yes you are going to need to be able to list it.

Comment: So, metadata is required to list files (e.g aquire id's) and the drive.file scope will prevent viewing and managing of files not opened or created by the app?

Comment: Well if you dont have metadata and you list files what exactly are you going to have permissions to see?  metadata is name size and stuff.   Drive.file will let you should only let you see files created within your app.   (not sure about that one never tested it)  if you dont want to open them you should use one of the readonlys i think

Comment: That's my point exactly. I would like to only see files created within my app,hence my choice of scope. Why drive.metadata is automatically included is what I'm curious about.

Comment: Thats the way it works Google probably doesn't have that kind of information.   These are the scopes we as developers are given